# pass env variables in make command in makefile

Tags: shell, variables, makefile, environment-variables

I am trying to pass a shell variable from one makefile command to another, but so far have not been successful.

```
target1:
     curl ... ${myvar} ## using myvar from target2

target2:
     export myvar=$(shell curl .....);
     echo $myvar
```

In the above case, I am not even getting the output on echo $myvar. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In a `Makefile`, every line of a target is run in a separate shell. Additionally, a command can only change the environment for itself and its children. So when you have:

```
target2:
     export myvar=$(shell curl .....);
     echo $myvar
```

And you run `make target2`, the following happens:

1. Make starts a shell that runs `export myvar=...some value...`
2. The shell exits.
3. Make runs another shell that runs `echo $myvar`
4. That shell exits.

First, there's a syntax problem here: when you write `$myvar`, this
will be interpreted by `make` as a request for the value `$m` followed
by the text `yvar`. To access shell variables, you need to escape the
`$`, like this:

```
echo $$myvar
```

But that won't solve this problem, because as we see from the above
sequence, the `export` command happens in a shell process which
immediately exits, so it's effectively invisible to anything else.

This target would work the way you expect if you were to write:

```
target2:
     export myvar=$(shell curl .....); \
     echo $$myvar
```

Here, because we're using the `\` to escape the end-of-line, this is
all one long "virtual" line and executes in a single shell process, so
the `echo` statement will see the variable value set in the previous
statement.

But nothing will make an environment variable set in a shell process
in one target visible in another target, because there's no way to get
these to execute in the same process.

If you need to set variables in your `Makefile` that are visible
across all targets, set `make` variables:

```
myvar = $(shell curl ...)

target1:
     curl ... $(myvar)
```

---

A workaround, as you have discovered, is to re-execute `make` as a
child process from within the process that set the environment
variable as in:

```
target2:
     export myvar=$(shell curl .....); \
     echo $$myvar; \
     $(MAKE) myvar=$$myvar
```

But often this sort of recursive call to `make` results in a more
complicated `Makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Posting if anyone comes across this. I needed to use $$ instead of $

```
target1:
     curl ... ${myvar} ## using myvar from target2
     
target2:
     export myvar=$(shell curl .....);
     echo $$myvar
     $(MAKE) myvar=$${myvar} target1
```

Comment: This still won't do what you want. See my answer for a longer explanation.