# How to export hostname in make file and use in compose file

Tags: makefile, docker-compose

I am working on docker and docker-compose file, where I need hostname. I am also using Makefile to start container. but this container need hostname.

Following is my Makefile where I start command and subcommand that executes.
This command does not export MY_HOST var value from `hostname -i`.

```
start:
   export MY_HOST=`hostname -i`
   echo ${MY_HOST}
   docker -f test.yml up -d
```

following is my docker-compose yml file where I want to use exported variable.

```
MyImage: 
  image:registry.test:latest
  restart:always
  environment:
    MY_HOST=${MY_HOST}
```

What's wrong with this code? can someone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is impossible to pass env variables from one Makefile command to another, because each line execute separately. But you can define variable and reuse it later this way:

```
MY_HOST := `hostname`

start:
    MY_HOST=${MY_HOST}\
        docker-compose run --rm shell env
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
MyImage: 
  image:registry.test:latest
  restart:always
  environment:
    - MY_HOST
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Values

also

https://makefiletutorial.com/#variables

and

[pass env variables in make command in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073516/pass-env-variables-in-make-command-in-makefile)